# Wildcard behavior in Windows DIR to show files in multiple subdirectories

Tags: windows, dir

I want to list files under both the Local and LocalLow directories under C:\Users\USERNAME\APPDATA but when I use the following command:

```
dir /s c:\users\me\appdata\Loca*
```

it only shows items matching Loca* under those 2 directories.

What i really want is [dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) or some other native Windows command line command to list items under both

```
c:\users\me\appdata\Local 
c:\users\me\appdata\LocalLow
```

How can I see the files from both of those directories?

Comment: It works for me (Windows 7)

Comment: _user30197_, which edition and version number of Windows are you using? please click on [edit] to add that to your original post.   In Windows 10 (ver 1709) I execute `dir /s c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\Loca*` and see all files in and under c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\Local but get no files from c:\users\USERNAME\appdata\LocalLow which is not what's reported to occur in Windows 7.